# Trait implementations must implement one of two methods

Tags: scala, inheritance

Say I have a trait like this:

```
trait Truthy {
   def isFalse = !isTrue
   def isTrue = !isFalse
}
```

Obviously, this will infinitely recurse if class extending the trait doesn't implement `isTrue` nor `isFalse` and one of them gets called.

I could leave either `isTrue` or `isFalse` without a default implementation, but then I'd have to pick and some implementations might have a very natural `isTrue` implementation while others might have a natural `isFalse` one.

Is there a way to force an extending class to implement one of the two methods without favoring one of them?

Comment: I guess the question is a simplification, as the easy way would be `final def isFalse = !isTrue` in the trait

Comment: That won't work, since it doesn't allow to provide an implementation of `isFalse` in a subclass.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to enforce such a constraint in Scala but you could use multiple traits to work around the issue; e.g.:

```
trait Truthy {
  def isFalse: Boolean
  def isTrue: Boolean
}

object Truthy {
  trait DeriveIsFalse {
    this: Truthy =>

    def isFalse = !isTrue
  }

  trait DeriveIsTrue {
    this: Truthy =>

    def isTrue = !isFalse
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
class MyImplementation extends Truthy with Truthy.DeriveIsTrue {
  def isFalse = someMeaningfulImplementation()
}
```

This is a way but there are definitely other ones if using multiple traits.